# How is Subleq code counted?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, answers, scoring

How are "bytes" counted in Subleq, in which code is a list of integers with no fixed size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from my own comment:

On Code Golf, languages are defined by implementations, and a quick search on Subleq gives multiple interpreters that take a list of integers in text, [written like this](https://github.com/howerj/subleq-python/blob/master/eforth.dec). For these interpreters, the score is simply the number of bytes of such a file.